# Erro no Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

Pessoal estou seguindo um post para começar a ver Node.JS e angular.

Aparentemente estava indo tudo bem até o momento que vou fazer o primeiro teste, que, de acordo com post, eu tenho que dar o comando "node bin\www" no CMD.
Porém quando eu dou esse comando ele apresenta a seguinte mensagem:

```html
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'http-errors'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\thaci\bau-node-mysql\bau-online\app.js:1:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

Após isso o post fala que é só eu ir no meu browser e colocal 'localhost:3000' e iria aparecer a os dados inseridos na minha tabela do MySQL.

O post pediu para eu mexer no arquivo 'app.js':

```js
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var mysql = require('mysql'),
    myConnection = require('express-myconnection');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.logger('dev'));

// It has to be registered somewhere before app.router
app.use(myConnection(mysql, {
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'thaci@11',
    port: 3306,
    database: 'devmedia_bau'
}, 'request'));

app.use(app.router);

app.get('/', routes.index);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

E também pediu para mexer no arquivo 'index.js':

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/*
 * GET home page.
 */

 router.get('/musicas', function(req, res){
     req.getConnection(function(err, connection){
         connection.query('SELECT * FROM tb_musicas', [], function(err, result){
             if(err){
                 return res.status(400).json(err);
             }
             return res.status(200).json(result);
         });
     });
 });

module.exports = router;

exports.index = function (req, res, next) {

    req.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        connection.query('SELECT ? AS RESULT', ['Hello World!'], function (err, results) {
            if (err) return next(err);

            res.render('index', {
                title: 'express-myconnection',
                result: results[0].RESULT
            });
        });
    });

};
```

No post não fala nada sobre, não achei nada na internet e eu não sei se é algo de errado no codigo ou se tenho que mexer em alguma configurações do Node.
Agradeço desde já qualquer ajuda! Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo pelo que esta descrito no seu erro, ele não esta encontrando o módulo `http-errors`.
Este módulo deve estar presente dentro da pasta `node_modules` que geralmente fica na raiz do projeto, junto com o arquivo app.js.
Se não tiver nem a pasta node_modules ou se ela estiver vazia deve ser porque você se esqueceu de dar o comando `npm install express`, ele vai instalar todas as dependências necessárias para você rodar seu projeto.
OBS: Você deve executar o comando `npm install express` pelo prompt/shell na raiz do seu projeto.

Comment: Oh rapaz, era isso mesmo mas engraçado que o post nem fala sobre esse comando kkkkk

Comment: Vixe cara, se o post que você esta seguindo não fala eu acho que seria melhor você seguir outro tutorial viu rsrsrs, talvez esse post que você esta seguindo deve estar considerando que os leitores já tenham mais experiência com o nodejs.

Comment: Pois é, vou ver outro mas acho que a parte mais chata pra mim é a conexão com o banco que agora é sucesso de resto talvez nem precise mais de tutorial